# Как переместить курсор в конец QTextEdit?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtextedit, qcursor

Я хочу сделать свой редактор кода на *Python* с помощью *PyQt5*. Я сделал функцию, которая будет упрощать написание текста. Например, пользователь написал "**`(`**", и в конец добавилось "**`)`**".

Функция работает, но из-за неё курсор возвращается в начало текста. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы курсор перемещался в конец. 
Как это сделать?

Если что, этот функционал я делал с помощью этого кода:

```
def onText(self):
    text = self.editor.toPlainText()
    if len(text) != 0 and text[len(text)-1] == '(':
        self.editor.setText(text + ')')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.textEdit = QTextEdit()        
        self.textEdit.textChanged.connect(self.text_changed)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.textEdit)
        
    def text_changed(self):
        text = self.textEdit.toPlainText()
#        if len(text) != 0 and text[len(text)-1] == '(':
        if text and text[-1] == '(':
            cursor = self.textEdit.textCursor()     
            cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor.End) 
            cursor.insertText(')')            
            self.textEdit.setTextCursor(cursor)        
        
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QFont("Times", 12, QFont.Bold))
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Работает, спасибо!

Comment: @VladosNX пожалуйста. Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

```
cursor = self.console.textCursor()
cursor.movePosition(QtGui.QTextCursor.End)
```

Вместо `console` подставь имя объекта класса `QTextEdit`

Comment: Не заработало :(